# Random Missing Controller Exception in CakePHP error logs

Tags: cakephp, exception, controller

I'm seeing random missing controller exceptions in CakePHP logs such as the following.

**Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImgController could not be found.**

**Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.**

In some cases we noticed these errors happen around the same time customers have complained that they are not able to use the application.

I've checked to make sure the folders are indeed there.  As I said this happens randomly.  So most of the times CSS and Images load fine.

Should I be custom handling these errors?  But why would these errors happen in the first place?

Could this be related to our hosting service provider?  Some IO problem?

Any help/thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

~Suresh

Comment: There are quite a few solutions to try [here](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Using-a-different-path-for-image-storage-td1313344.html). Your .htaccess files might need to have a few lines added as mentioned to not resolve links to resources that don't exist on your server.

Comment: who you include your css and images files in your HTML/PHP code???